Is it possible to change destination coordinates in the middle of a hyperspace jump?
As seen in "Bad Batch" Se2Ep13 "Pabu", the Clone Force 99 are on hyperspace jump and Gee Phenoa gives them a new set of coordinates and they go "on the fly".
I've always thought the hyperspace jump must be completed to make another one to a new destination. Anyone can confirm this?

I mean... clearly it's possible, because as you said, we see them do it in the episode.

I see a potential conflict between this jump and 15 years later when Ben and Luke leave Tatooine where Solo explains having to wait for computer calculations (at sub-light speed) to jump "Without precise calculations, we'd fly right through a star or bounce too close to a supernova, and that would end your trip real quick, wouldn't it?" Of course maybe the navi-computer on the Falcon is 50 years old"

Don't forget it's just fiction, so what ever works for the story : )

Yes, it is impossible to change coordinates, as seen on episode 13 "Jedi Crash", of The Clone Wars.
In this case, they introduce wrong coordinates, fly towards a star, and must restart all power on the ship to change them.

General Secura, we have a problem.
What is it, commander?
In our haste to escape, the navicomputer's coordinates were inputted incorrectly.
And, we're headed right for a star. It's no use. The navigation computer is completely fried.
Shut down all power circuits to reset the coordinates.


Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to include any relevant quotes from the episode you mentioned.

Thank you for your help and for welcoming me.

Nice job with the edit. :-)

Loosely implied in Empire Strikes Back when Admiral Ozzel chooses to bring the attacking Imperial fleet out of hyperspace "too close" to Hoth, suggesting the exit coordinates were not pre-determined. Maybe backed up by the existence of the Imperial Interdictor cruiser (seen in Rebels season two, introduced in Star Wars: The Roleplaying Game before Timothy Zahn used them in his Thrawn trilogy) -- If the Interdictor can pull you out of hyperspace along your route then travel is not solely to a predefined point.
